# Programmatic calls to npm from node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am writing a custom command line interface (CLI) to manage some other packages to be installed or uninstalled with `npm`. Would it be better to call npm via `spawn('npm')` or `require('npm')`?

```
require('child_process').spawn;
var _npm = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'npm.cmd' : 'npm';
var npm = spawn(_npm, ['install', source]);
```

or:

```
require('npm').commands.install(source, function (err, data) {
  ...
});
```

I have the `spawn` approach in place, but already ran into one issue with `spawn` on windows. Wondering if using `require('npm')` would help mitigate other unforeseen issues?

Are there any major disadvantages to switching to `require('npm'), other than the lack of documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> require('npm') would help mitigate other unforeseen issues?

Generally yes, if some library provides a direct javascript API, that is going to be the preferred option for integrating with your own javascript program.

The [docs are here](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/api/npm.html). I agree they are a bit slim, but if you understand the command line interface, the API is going to make a lot of sense. Plus it's open source so don't be afraid to read the source.

Comment: The npm API is not really stable at all, and not really recommended for use.